# Calculating differences between values in a vector

Tags: r, difference

[image: I'll] I have a vector that contains just over quarter of a million values (I know, a huge amount) and I need to  calculate the difference of each value from each other. So for example, with the first value 202.7952, I want to calculate the difference between every other value in my vector with 202.7952 and restrict it so that differences above 400 are discarded. Then, I want it to take the second value (202.7956) and do the same thing (including with the value above). The end result of this I hope will be a list of values that are the calculated differences of the values in my vector. For example:-

```
0.0004
0.0125
0.0136
etc
```

would be produced from taking the difference for the first value from the next three values in the list, and it continuing on to the bottom before doing the same thing but for the second value in the list. However, as I have a quarter of a million values in my vector, I know there may be some computational problem. I've produced an image to show the distribution of my data:-

[image]

The values I have range from 200 to 1500, with the vast majority of the values falling within the 200-500 range. I've tried to do this in java but I run into memory issues, so do any of you think/know if it's possible to do this in R and how I could go about doing so?

This is my java code:-

```
public class matrixDiff {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        double[] values = new double[271730];                       

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file"));

        String value = br.readLine();

        for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){

            if(value != null){

                values[i] = Double.parseDouble(value);
            }

            value = br.readLine();

        }

        for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){

            double mzValue = values[i];

            System.out.println(mzValue);

            for(int j = 0; j < values.length; j++){

                double diff = values[j];


                if((diff - mzValue) < 400 || (diff - mzValue) > -400){

                    System.out.println(diff - mzValue);

                }

            }

        }


    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You can definitely do this in R, but you can also definitely do this in Java. If you already know the basics of Java, I would spend some time learning how to optimize that code rather than trying to learn a new language just for this not very specialized purpose.

Comment: Might be a good idea to find out how many values are over 400 first, then go about choosing a method.  The vector might get a lot smaller, and 250k isn't really a problem for R

Comment: Just curious, what do you need to do with those differences next?

Comment: With the differences I basically need to determine their frequency i.e. how frequent the values are. Also in terms of Java, I've already made some code for it, but again I keep coming up with memory issues. I'll post my code onto the post now. Also the 250k isn't the problem, it's the number of values that will be produced from taking the differences of 250k values from almost 250k values (so effectively almost producing 62500000 values, but of course as we're limiting the differences to only 400 or less it should be less than that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how you could proceed. Sample data of size 1000.

```
memory.limit(max = NA)
# filter out differences larger than K
K = 25

v <- rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 200, sd = 10)
diffs <- list()
for(i in seq_along(v)) {
  diffs[[i]] <- v[i] - v
  diffs[[i]] <- diffs[[i]][diffs[[i]] <= K]
}


# Check lengths after filtering
sapply(diffs, length)
```

**EDIT**

I don't know if you considered it or if you solved your problem already, but to deal with that amount of data, one thing you could do it to store everything in a database. For instance:

```
library(RSQLite)
con <- dbConnect(SQLite(), "diffs.sqlite")
memory.size(max = NA)
v <- rnorm(n = 100000, mean = 200, sd = 10)

# filter out differences larger than K
K = 25

for(i in seq_along(v)) {
  diffs <- v[i] - v
  diffs <- diffs[diffs <= K]
  dbWriteTable(con, "mytable", as.data.frame(diffs), append=TRUE)
}
```

Then there's stuff you could do using SQL rather than R functions and that would not create memory problems.

Comment: I just realized that for much larger sample size, I also run into memory problems. Will try to think of something...

Comment: Haha yeah this is the ballache of this problem, but thank you!

Comment: I've managed to limit my data so that there's only 58000 values now so I'm going to try and see if it works now

Comment: Oh ok, just added the database avenue but keep us posted in any case!

Comment: Yes no problem, just need 5 minutes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72929/discussion-between-dominic-comtois-and-user2062207).

Comment: Apologies I'm back now

Answer (score 3):

Vectors are your friends in R. Huge time and memory saver.

Data frame example:

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000000))
df$dif <- df$x - c(NA, df$x[1:(length(df$x)-1)])
```

There you go, difference of 1kk numbers in a blink of an eye.

Vector example:

```
x <- rnorm(1000000)
x <- c(NA, x[1:(length(x)-1)])
```

Or even shorter:

```
x <- rnorm(1000000)
x <- c(NA, diff(x))
```

To accumulate values through the vector you'll need cumsum():

```
x <- rnorm(1000000)
x <- cumsum(c(0, diff(x)))
```

Note the 0 insted of NA.

Comment: Thanks for that! I've just tried it with my data, so I did:- `maldi$dif <- maldi$x - c(NA, maldi$x[1:(length(df$x)-1)])` but I get the following message:- `Error in maldi$x : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Comment: woops sorry I typed that out wrong, this is what I did:-
`> maldi$dif <- maldi$x - c(NA, maldi$x[1:(length(maldi$x)-1)])
Error in maldi$x : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`
Could it be the case that `df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000000))` comes out as a data frame as it comes out true for is.data.frame and that my maldi object isn't?

Comment: Why not just `c(NA, diff(df$x))`? You are reinventing the wheel here.

Comment: Well, code is simple enough and sort of shows what is being done. Kinda helps with explaining how vectors work because the essence of this problem was understanding difference between vectorized operation and a loop.

Comment: For some reason I continue to get the same error message of $ operator being invalid for atomic vectors despite `> is.vector(maldi)
[1] TRUE`

Comment: @user2062207 - try df <- data.frame(x = maldi) and then run the code. The $ operator points to column in data frame. For vectors code doesn't require the $x part.

Comment: Ah yeah it works! I'm really sorry I probably should of been clearer in my post, but the idea was that it would look at the first value in the vector and take the difference of every other value in the vector from that first value before then moving on the second value. For example, with the values x1, x2, x3, x4, x5:-

 `x2 - x1, x3 - x1, x4 - x1, x5 -x1
 x1 - x2, x3 - x2, x4 - x2, x5 - x2
 x1 - x3, x2 - x3, x4 - x3, x5 - x3`

Comment: Is there by any chance a way of doing the cumsum(x) but in a way that it doesn't just take the first value and calculates the differences with every other value in the vector, but it also takes the second value of the vector and does the same thing?

Comment: I'd suggest you to edit your initial question, add data set and desired outcome(s). Then I'll adjust my answer accordingly. I'm not sure I understood this one correctly.